# How to configure code style in IntelliJ Idea to achieve indented super class and interfaces

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I try to achieve code style:

```
public class NewCoolClassWithFeatures<T extends InternalWrappedClass>
        extends
            SuperClassParametrizedT<T>
        implements
            SomeLongInterfaceName, AnotherLongInterfaceName {

}
```

But IDE (IntelliJ Idea 12) removes indents before super class definition and implemented interfaces.

Comment: If remove the newlines after `extends` and after `implements`, can you live with that style?

Comment: I want to achieve readability of complicated class definitions